# docker-compose and nginx: always getting 127.0.0.1 as client IP

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

I've created a Docker image which contains nginx server (manually installed, not using the nginx docker image). Wherever I access the web server from, I always see `127.0.0.1` as client IP address. I fronted the container with system's nginx as a reverse proxy, same. I access the nginx container from the public IP, always `127.0.0.1`.

```yaml
version: "3.6"

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.30.253.0/24"
          gateway: "172.30.253.1"
services:
  ##
  ##  WEBAPP container
  ##
  app-web:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_webapp
    image: "my/app:${APP_VERSION}"
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "8000"
    ports:
      - 3380:8000
    networks:
      docker-network:
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=${APP_NAME}_db
      - DB_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}
      - DB_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - DB_NAME=${MYSQL_DATABASE}

  ##
  ##  DATABASE CONFIG
  ##
  docker-mysql:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: "mariadb:10.6"
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - 3316:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql:cached
      - ./mysql/conf/yetopen.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/yetopen.cnf:ro,delegated
      - ./mysql-files:/var/lib/mysql-files
    networks:
      docker-network:

  ##
  ##  ADMINER
  ##
  adminer:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_adminer
    # Non official adminer with dblib included
    image: dehy/adminer:4.8.1
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      - ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER=${APP_NAME}_db
    ports:
      - 3382:8080
    networks:
      docker-network:
```

The container's nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    root /var/www/web;
    index index.php;
    server_name _;

    # Set real IP address in the Docker network defined in docker-compose.yml
    set_real_ip_from  172.30.253.0/24;
    real_ip_header    X-Real-IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

In PHP I correctly see `REMOTE_ADDR` to the client's IP, and for the same request, in nginx log I see 127.0.0.1!

Answer (score 0):

This was a misconfiguration of nginx. I omitted to say the image is a Debian-based one, with nginx installed via `apt`. I was looking at the image logs and only seeing access from 127.0.0.1:

```
mis_webapp   | 127.0.0.1 -  11/Nov/2022:20:33:24 +0000 "GET /index.php" 302
mis_webapp   | 127.0.0.1 -  11/Nov/2022:20:33:25 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
mis_webapp   | 127.0.0.1 -  11/Nov/2022:20:33:28 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
mis_webapp   | 127.0.0.1 -  11/Nov/2022:22:18:28 +0000 "GET /index.php" 302
mis_webapp   | 127.0.0.1 -  11/Nov/2022:22:18:29 +0000 "GET /index.php" 302
```

Instead, the full log is, as normally, in `/var/log/nginx/access.log`. :/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).